# Drawing a blank on the [whiteboard] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, meta-tags

There is a tag [whiteboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whiteboard) which as of writing has 78 questions, and no tag information or wiki explaining what it is meant to be used for.

- Some of the questions are about making digital whiteboard software. Using the tag for this purpose makes it a meta-tag since it is about what project the asker is working on, not an area of programming expertise. The content of questions about this would be better described by tags like [drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drawing), [paint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paint), [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas), [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface), [touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch), [wacom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wacom) or so on.
- Others seem to be about a particular piece of software named Microsoft Whiteboard, and should be closed as off-topic since they are "about general computing", not programming.
- A few others are asking for suggestions or recommendations for digital whiteboard software, and should likewise be closed.

What should we do with the tag?

Comment: It looks like [\[osgi\] \[whiteboard\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osgi+whiteboard) refers to the ["The Whiteboard Pattern"](https://docs.osgi.org/whitepaper/whiteboard-pattern/020-background.html#the-whiteboard-pattern) / [http whiteboard](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.http.whiteboard.html#org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard). I don't know enough on the topic to know whether this tag is necessary and should be renamed to something like [osgi-whiteboard] or [http-whiteboard] or something, or if it's fine to be removed.

Comment: Erase the [whiteboard] tag.

Comment: Worth mentioning there are [2k questions with the word whiteboard](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=whiteboard). However with the exception mentioned in Henry Ecker's comment I don't see any reason to keep the tag for the questions that are currently tagged with it.

Comment: There's apparently a [`[blackboard]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bblackboard%5D&searchOn=3) design pattern amongst many other off-topic questions with only a few relating to the educational software API.  Let's be equal opportunity with our board erasing!